# CSS stylesheet not linking to the HTML

Tags: html, css

I don't know why my CSS stylesheet and HTML files are not linking.

This is my code in the HTML file.

```
<head>
    <title>Website Sample</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\web\style.css" />

</head>
```

This is the CSS

```
.section2 {
  height: 3000px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use Windows style links. Change it to `file:///` url:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file:///C:/Users/Sam/Desktop/web/style.css" />
```

Also it is always better to give relative paths, instead of absolute, as it is flexible wherever it is hosted, plus helps when you want to migrate it.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
```

An update to the current HTML Standards, it's not necessary to have `type` attribute for `<link>` and `<script>` tags. So you can further reduce it down to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
```

Comment: @SamYounes Can you let us know what is the directory structure and where is your HTML and CSS files?

Answer (score 2):

Check this path,

You can't give the absolute path from your root, you need to pass the

> relative path

Please check the link as below:

```
<link href="web/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: plus 1 for can't give c drive path,

Comment: @shas LoL. So D drive path valid? `:P`

Comment: should give relative path.. absolute path coding is not good. @PraveenKumar

Comment: @shas You didn't understand the sarcasm I had in the comment. Never mind.

Answer (score 2):

Kepp the css file in the same folder as the HTML file and then provide the css file name:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
```

Or provide relative path, supposing you keep css files in a folder named 'css', like :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />
```

Or like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/style.css" />
```

where '~' symbolizes your root directory.

Comment: Wow! Nice to see there's something new `~`. Where's that given? Any documentation? Also I believe this is used only on *nix based systems for the home folder. Are you meaning that?

Comment: plus 1 for the linux style directory structure